# What is the least amount of time that I can measure using STM32F1x Timers?

Tags: stm32, arm, cortex-m3, stm32f10x

I am working with STM32F107 on a custom board, the board has 12MHz crystal. I want to measure 1 micro second precisely, but I am unable to do so.
I have used STM32CubeMX to set the core clock at 72MHz which is it's maximum speed. 
Trying to use Timer 3 in upcounting mode and toggling a GPIO in the ISR of the Timer.
These are my settings

```
void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 72-1;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
}
```

I get a approximate 2 micro second pulse on the scope.
Tried fiddling around with the prescaler and period values but I am unable to get a 1 micro second pulse.

Comment: The **least amount** you can measure is 0. Do you mean highest **Resolution** (smallest \$\Delta t\$)?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the description. Are you trying to use your STM32F107 to **measure** a pulse or are you trying to use it to **make** a pulse?

Comment: I want to know the resolution and I am trying to make a pulse.

Comment: Well your timer triggers an interrupt in every uS but the HAL IRQ handler and the `HAL_GPIO_Toggle` call give some overhead.

Comment: You aren't measuring time . instead you are using the timer to generate a pulse. Two different things.

Comment: Is there any way I can make the overhead as less as possible ?

Comment: You can look into their implementation and strip of what is not necessary. Replace them with your own functions that only access the necessary registers and bits.

What kind of pulse do you want to achieve? Frequency, duty cycle? Won't be a PWM signal better?

Comment: I am using the GPIO toggle  just to measure the pulse on the oscilloscope but in reality I want to achieve a delay of 1 microsecond

Comment: To get exactly 1µs you need to generate the pulse directly from the timer. A general-purpose timer should be able to do that, though you may be limited in the choice of the output pin.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use the MCO function. Did you consider this ?

Comment: MCO is one way of doing it but then I am ristriced on the Pins to use.

Comment: HAL has a lot of things that introduced latency. I removed the portion of HAL calls that I do not need and kept only what is required. After that the code seems to work fine.

Comment: There is another method that worked for me.

I initialized the timer without interrupts and wrote the delay loop as follows

`void My_Delay(uint32_t delay)
{
 
 HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
        ticks = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim3);
 while(__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim3) - ticks <= delay)
 {

 }
 HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim3);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Since your controller is running at 72 MHz, the minimum delay between two consecutive instructions is 1/72 µs. The internal flash is not fast enough for that, you must run your program from the internal RAM to achieve this.

To obtain a delay of exactly 1 µs, create a sequence of assembly instructions that takes exactly 71 cycles to complete. Get rid of HAL, it's too complicated and hence unpredictable for this kind of work. The trivial approach would be a sequence of 71 `NOP` instructions, but that's a bit wasteful. In order to construct some loop in inline assembly, you'd have to consult the cycle counts of [processor instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100165_0201_00_en/ric1414056333562.html) and [addressing modes](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100165_0201_00_en/ric1417175925887.html). To run it from flash, take flash latency and prefetch buffer behavior into account, as described in chapter 3.3.3 of the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf).

Comment: Why use a software delay when you have hardware timers?

Comment: Yes, this method is also feasible. But I was looking for a way to achieve this with a timer.

Comment: The interrupt system is not fast enough for this kind of accuracy. Interrupt entry takes about 12 cycles under ideal conditions. With flash prefetch, possibly interrupting an unaligned access, etc, it could easily reach 18. That's already 0.25 µs late, before you even start loading the registers necessary to get any real work done. The latency can also become substantially lower, down to about 6 cycles, or 0.08 µs, when the inetrrupt occurs at the "lucky spots" before or after another interrupt (late arriving or tail chaining cases)

Comment: To generate a pulse you could probably do without an interrupt and just get the timer hardware to do it, depending on the part and pins available.